# Session variable loses value after redirection

Tags: php, session

I have three files.

File 1: index.php

which redirects to second.php and sends id=$var to second.php.

code:

```
$var=52013;
window.open('second.php?id=$var','name','width=1000,height=700,scrollbars=yes');
```

File 2: second.php

In this file I have received `$var`, when I print it in logs it displays value of `$var`.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['id'] = $_REQUEST['id'];
$GLOBALS["log"]->fatal("Get id of order = ".$_SESSION['id']);

//Here it redirects to third file for some varification online.
//This condition is true first time when this page is called but after
//redirection from third.php this condition becomes false.So code below
//this if statement will be executed after redirection from third file.

if(condition==true)
{
    header("Location: http://third.php");
}

print "Please visit:\n$authUrl\n\n";
print "Please enter the auth code:\n";

//After redirection from third.php i want to write document using value stored
//in session variable which we get at top.($_SESSION['id'])

$val = $_SESSION['id'];

//Write a file
$file_open = fopen("modules/doc/views/document.txt","wb");

$content = $val;
fwrite($file_open,$content);

fclose($file_open);
```

File 3: Third.php

This file do some varification online and then redirect to second.php in order to write session id in document.txt

---

So the problem is that when third.php redirects to second.php file the session variable loses its value. I want to write the value of session variable in document.txt after redirection from third.php but at that time `$_SESSION['id']` contains nothing.

But the process should be same, I don't want to change it. It's the requirement.

i.e index.php -> second.php -> third.php -> second.php -> write session value.

Thanks

Comment: To clarify, all the .php files mentioned above contain session_start() before any other session-related logic, correct?

Answer (score 0):

at the begining of the second.php you do this:

> session_start();
>
> $_SESSION['id'] = $_REQUEST['id'];

which is clears the session, and puts into $_SESSION['id'] whatever was received in $_REQUEST['id']. That is why you have nothing in $_SESSION['id'] when commint from third.php. Note that when you do this:

> window.open('second.php?id=$var' ...

you just send string '$var' in id

Comment: No i got its value..I think you have not understand my problem